# How to sort or reorder MergeCursor for ListViewAdapter

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-studio, cursor

I am developing a simple social media for my case study. I was able to retrieve the post from the people the user follows. Here's the screenshot:

[image]

As you can see, the problem is that the posts were not sorted according to date/id. Instead, it is sorted according to the people the user follows. It is because I am only merging the cursors using mergecursor. Here's a part of my code:

```
    ListView listviewFeed = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listviewFeed);
    Cursor cursorFeed = DataAdapters.getFeed(dbHelper, strUserID);
    //This code is for retrieving user's own posts

    Cursor cursorFollowing = DataAdapters.getFollowing(dbHelper,strUserID);
    //This code is for retrieving the followed users.

    if(cursorFollowing.getCount()>0) {
        for (int intCtr = 0; intCtr < cursorFollowing.getCount(); intCtr++) {
            int intUseridI = cursorFollowing.getColumnIndex(Tables.FollowTable.COLUMN_USERID);
            String strUseridI = cursorFollowing.getString(intUseridI);

            Cursor cursorFollowingFeed = DataAdapters.getFeed(dbHelper, strUseridI);
            \\This code is for retrieving the posts of the people the user follows.

            if(intCtr>0)
            {
                mergeCursor = new MergeCursor(new Cursor[]{mergeCursor, cursorFollowingFeed});
            }else {
                mergeCursor = new MergeCursor(new Cursor[]{cursorFeed, cursorFollowingFeed});
            }
            //This code is for merging the cursors.

            if (intCtr + 1 == cursorFollowing.getCount()) {
                cursorFollowing.close();
            } else {
                cursorFollowing.moveToNext();
            }
        }
        ListViewAdapterMeasurement adapterMeasurement = new ListViewAdapterMeasurement(this, mergeCursor);
        listviewFeed.setAdapter(adapterMeasurement);
    }else
    {
        ListViewAdapterMeasurement adapterMeasurement = new ListViewAdapterMeasurement(this, cursorFeed);
        listviewFeed.setAdapter(adapterMeasurement);
    }
```

It is all working well. I just want to order the posts by Date or by ID.

Is there any way to sort MergeCursor?

Comment: do not use MergeCursor ... add `getAllFollowingFeeds` and use INNER JOIN there

Comment: Thankyou for your answer :) I've managed to solve my problem and you gave me an idea to change my query :) @Selvin

Answer (score 0):

I guess there is no way to sort the MergeCursor so I tried to think of other ways.

I changed my query like this:

```
public static Cursor getFeed (DBHelper dbHelper, String strUserID)
{
    SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursorFollowing = getFollowing(dbHelper,strUserID);

    String strQuery = "SELECT * FROM feed_tbl WHERE "+ Tables.FeedTable.COLUMN_USERID + "="+strUserID;
    if(cursorFollowing.getCount()>0)
    {

        for(int intCtr=0;intCtr<cursorFollowing.getCount();intCtr++)
        {
            int intUseridI = cursorFollowing.getColumnIndex(Tables.FollowTable.COLUMN_USERID);
            String strUseridI = cursorFollowing.getString(intUseridI);
            String strConcatQuery = " OR "+ Tables.FeedTable.COLUMN_USERID + "="+strUseridI;

            if (intCtr + 1 == cursorFollowing.getCount()) {
                cursorFollowing.close();
            } else {
                cursorFollowing.moveToNext();
            }
            strQuery = strQuery +""+strConcatQuery;
            Log.v(TAG,strQuery);

        }
    }
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(strQuery+" ORDER BY "+ Tables.FeedTable.COLUMN_ID + " DESC",null);
    if (cursor != null) {
        cursor.moveToFirst();
    }
    return cursor;
}
```

The result on the log tag is this:

**V/FeedMe: SELECT * FROM feed_tbl WHERE feed_userid=1 OR feed_userid=2 OR feed_userid=4 OR feed_userid=5**

Just to make things clear to those who have the same problem with me which is about MergeCursor sorting. THERE IS NO SUCH WAY TO SORT MERGECURSOR :)

Thankyou!